# Ui select select box array in scope model value not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Sorry for my English.
I'm using UI-Select select box to view the data, but i'm printing the data using ng-model value is throwing undefined. Im using basic array.

Comment: the below link to check, this is my sample
http://plnkr.co/edit/sQ50FJVaw0flrLJFzUD3?p=preview

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code here.

Comment: Plese try below link 
http://plnkr.co/edit/xFGkdH2nmosLec5Gd0QH?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by intializing an object in the controller and updating a property of that object instead of directly updating the scope variable.

Please visit this [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/1353) to know more.

Below is a working Example with the solution.

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $interval) {
  $scope.karthi = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10];
  $scope.ctrl = {};
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demo">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS ui-select</title>

  <!--
      IE8 support, see AngularJS Internet Explorer Compatibility https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie
      For Firefox 3.6, you will also need to include jQuery and ECMAScript 5 shim
    -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/2.2.0/es5-shim.js"></script>
      <script>
        document.createElement('ui-select');
        document.createElement('ui-select-match');
        document.createElement('ui-select-choices');
      </script>
    <![endif]-->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ui-select files -->
  <script src="./select.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./select.css">

  <script src="./demo.js"></script>

  <!-- themes -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.default.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.min.css" />
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    .select2>.select2-choice.ui-select-match {
      /* Because of the inclusion of Bootstrap */
      height: 29px;
    }
    
    .selectize-control>.selectize-dropdown {
      top: 36px;
    }
    /* Some additional styling to demonstrate that append-to-body helps achieve the proper z-index layering. */
    
    .select-box {
      background: #fff;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .alert-info.positioned {
      margin-top: 1em;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10000;
      /* The select2 dropdown has a z-index of 9999 */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">


    <h3>Selectize theme</h3>
    <p>Selected: {{ctrl.asdf}}</p>
    <ui-select ng-model="ctrl.asdf" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a country">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="country in karthi | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="country | highlight: $select.search"></span>
        <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
      </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @karthicks If your issue is resolved, then close the issue!